# Structure Declaration in C

Tags: c++, struct, typedef

I get the error when identifier not found in this snippet. Please help what is the bug

```
typedef struct
 {
  Int32   frameID;
  Int32   slotIndx;
  Int32   symNumber;

 }ControlList, *controlListPtr;
```

Thanks

Comment: Your title says `C`, but it's tagged as `C++`. Which one is it? Also, what is the "identifier not found" error? What is the exact compiler error message that you got?

Comment: What's the actual error? Is "Int32" defined?

Answer (score 3):

probably the identifier Int32 was not found. try this:

```
#include <stdint.h>
typedef int32_t Int32;

typedef struct
{
    Int32   frameID;
    Int32   slotIndx;
    Int32   symNumber;
} ControlList, *controlListPtr;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `Int32` is a buildin type. Try `#include<stdtype.h>` and use `int32` instead?

Comment: `stdtype.h` and `int32`? Don't you mean `stdint.h` and `int32_t`?

Answer (score 0):

`Int32` is not a built in type. As you're using `Int32` as type of structure member variables, you got "identifier not found" error I guess. Most likely, `Int32` is defined somewhere else in your project. If that is a header file, you need to `#include` that header file in your files where you use `Int32`. If `Int32` is not defined anywhere, you need to define it with something meaningful for you.

Comment: I have #included DataTypes.h file where I do typedefs. So that is not the problem.
I face this issue during debugging, watch window. I found that other variables were
visible. Only structures were not.

When I did following, I got structure in watch window without error "Identifier not found"

controlListPtr->frameID=0;

I dont know the reason why

Comment: `*controlListPtr` is a type. you cannot use it like that. you can try: `ControlList cl; controlListPtr cp = &cl; cp->frameID = 10; cout << cp->frameID << endl;`